# What should i use instead of eth0:1 if it is deprecated

Tags: networking, centos, ip, centos7, ip-aliasing

usually i create `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1`
and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:2` but i seen in internet that it is deprecated using eth0 **:1**

so what can i use to the VPS use the additional IPs?

usually my files was:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=164.132.193.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
GATEWAY=164.132.192.1
```

and the new ones

in ifcfg-eth0:1

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=91.134.28.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
```

and in ifcfg-eth0:2 :

```
DEVICE=eth0:2
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=91.134.158.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
```

**how should i do now?
to use the additional IPs since that is deprecated?**

i saw this [Persist IP address alias across reboots in CentOS/RHEL 6 using "ip" command](https://serverfault.com/questions/461533/persist-ip-address-alias-across-reboots-in-centos-rhel-6-using-ip-command)

but i don't know the additional ip gateways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually super simple. Try something like:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=164.132.193.xxx
IPADDR2=91.134.28.xxx
IPADDR3=91.134.158.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
GATEWAY=164.132.192.1
```