# ARP request for itself

Tags: linux, networking, arp

I have two IPs assigned to the same interface (host A):

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a4:bf:01:24:f8:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.10.200.22/24 brd 10.10.100.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.10.200.155/32 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and some service listening on `10.10.200.155:80`. When I'm trying to telnet port 80 the connection is hanging (source address `10.10.201.2`, host B). `tcpdump` on host A shows me sth like this (repeating):

```
# tcpdump -n -i any dst 10.10.200.155
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
21:52:16.894558 IP 10.10.201.2.60262 > 10.10.200.155.80: Flags [S], seq 1239565567, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1965969834 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:52:17.893363 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.200.155 tell 10.10.200.155, length 28
21:52:17.893732 IP 10.10.201.2.60262 > 10.10.200.155.80: Flags [S], seq 1239565567, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1965970084 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:52:18.893319 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.200.155 tell 10.10.200.155, length 28
21:52:19.893374 IP 10.10.200.155 > 10.10.200.155: ICMP host 10.10.201.2 unreachable, length 68
21:52:19.893385 IP 10.10.200.155 > 10.10.200.155: ICMP host 10.10.201.2 unreachable, length 68
21:52:19.893393 IP 10.10.200.155 > 10.10.200.155: ICMP host 10.10.201.2 unreachable, length 68
21:52:19.893400 IP 10.10.200.155 > 10.10.200.155: ICMP host 10.10.201.2 unreachable, length 68
21:52:19.897746 IP 10.10.201.2.60262 > 10.10.200.155.80: Flags [S], seq 1239565567, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1965970585 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Some communication reaches `10.10.200.155` but there are strange(?) ARP requests from `10.10.200.155` asking for itself, is it ok? There is no other traffic in background so all those packets are generated on telneting. On host A `tcpdump` shows nothing for `tcpdump -n -i any dst 10.10.201.2`. Routes for those addresses:

```
10.10.200.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.200.22 
10.10.201.2 via 10.10.200.155 dev eth1
```

Do you have any idea why traffic can't pass back to `10.10.201.2`?

Answer (score 0):

Your second IP seems wrong. You are assigning another IP with a different subnet mask (/32).

Assign a secondary IP with the same subnet mask. You have examples here in the comment: [Persist IP address alias across reboots in CentOS/RHEL 6 using "ip" command](https://serverfault.com/questions/461533/persist-ip-address-alias-across-reboots-in-centos-rhel-6-using-ip-command)

Comment: With `10.10.200.155/24` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found some temporary workaround. After adding new IP to the interface I have to `flush` related route and add it one more time..
Then communication works perfectly. Does anyone know why it happen like this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me in a slightly different way, the root cause was a mistake in my 'ip route add' command, instead of doing 'ip route add via **<remote gateway IP address>** dev <local interface>' I did 'ip route add via **<local interface IP address>** dev <local interface>'.  I'm not saying that's your issue but just check.