# added a new network interface, lost connectivity

Tags: linux-networking, rhel7, operating-system

After adding new subnet ip to new interface, the new ip was being used in previous interface em1 like so: ifcfg-em1:3  ... when I moved the IP to ifcfg-em2 and issued the following command `ifdown ifcfg-em1:3`
   I lost my connection to ifcfg-em1 until i rebooted the machine. then I was able to get into the OS using ifcfg-em1 and ifcfg-em2 was useable also.

Just wondering why did I have to reboot?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because you set them up incorrectly to begin with. You should be using [this method](https://serverfault.com/a/461536/126632) because interface "aliases" like em1:3 are many years obsolete.